# Log4j2-Log records parallely in other location

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j2

I have a simple Netty Server code that runs on a dedicated server. My Netty code logs whatever requests it receives and whatever responses it sends in a simple file. I am using log4j2 for logging asynchronously. I want to log the same records into another file that is in different machine. Because, currently I can't relay on the Server as it may crash anytime and I don't want lose my logs. How can I log the records parallel onto different machine so that I will create two copies of the records, one is in Server machine and other is in different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can do the following:

1. Mount a network folder phisicall located on your ANOTHER_MACHINE to your SERVER_MACHINE.
2. Set up additional appender that writes log to that folder.
3. Add that appender to your logger.

Or

1. Deploy [Apache Flume](http://flume.apache.org/index.html)
2. Use [Flume](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender) Appender

Or

1. Deploy some SysLog server on your OTHER_MACHINE
2. Use [Syslog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) appender